# React Component in Meteor Package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, meteor-packages

### Solved on 2017-10-23 [See Below]

I'm trying to write React Components as Meteor Packages and i think i do something terribly wrong somewhere and i can't find any samples anywhere online.

I Have my Package setup like this:

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'bardia:mapackage',
  version: '0.0.1',
  summary: '',
  documentation: 'README.md'
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.5.2');
  api.use('ecmascript');
  api.mainModule('mapackage.js');
});
```

And my mapackage.js as

```
import Comps from './Comps';

export const name = Comps;
```

and my react component like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Comps extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         welll this lah
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Comps;
```

and when importing it to my main App as:

```
import {name} from 'meteor/bardia:mapackage'
const App = props => (
  <center>{name}</center>
);
```

it returns as just

```
<center data-reactroot=""></center>
```

> If i replace export const name = Comps to export const name = 'Comps'; it will render 'Comps'. meaning, it only renders the string.

how can i get to work !?

Comment: You should post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: @MasterAM good idea, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after talking to another developer, i managed to get a better understanding on how the components were being rendered. As a solution i Used React-Router to redirect to each components, as i initially wanted it to be that way.

I'm using [CleverBeagle Pup](https://cleverbeagle.com/pup/v1/introduction) Boilerplate , Nothing fancy about it it's a minimal Meteor - React package that provides the tools you need without overcomplicating things.

if you want to get my running code, clone this repo : [REPO](https://bitbucket.org/bardiaheshmati/package-test.git)

once you cloned it , run `Meteor npm install` in the folder and `npm start`
, [Read More](https://cleverbeagle.com/pup/v1/getting-started)

in the package folder i created a sample package, called `Mapackage`, that's where all the magic happens. I'll commit changes to this repo as i'm doing my tests.

---

### Comps.jsx

This is just a simple react component, to be exported

### Mapackage.js

```
//Import Components that are going to be exported as Routes
import Comps from './Comps';

//Export Router and their components
const MaPack = ()=>{
  return(
    <div>
      <Route path='/maPack' exact={true} component={Comps} />
      //if you want more functionality on your routes
      <Route path='/maPack/:_id' exact={true} component={subMaPack} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

---

Once you're done with this you can simply import the Route comonent to your Router or Switch [Read More](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic)